# How can I prevent Cloudfront from throwing a 403 error when it encounters the word "localhost" in the body of a request?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I bumped into a strange error. Every time there is a word "localhost" in the body of requests that are fired from front end to back end and go through Cloudfront, Cloudfront returns [403 ERROR The request could not be satisfied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45XEi.png). Is it an issue with our Cloudfront setup or is it a system-wide issue? Unfortunately I do not have full access to Cloudfront setup, but the DevOps has provided me with behaviours configures there. The only rule there is [redirection from http to https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPyxD.png). Regardless of where the issue comes from, can it be fixed by adding some extra rule atop of the existing Cloudfront configuration? What are some other potentials fixes?

Comment: Maybe there is a AWS WAF involved?

Comment: It could also be a cors issue.

Comment: Related https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudfront-troubleshoot-403-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to @rjdkolb. The issue was caused by AWS WAF. Particularly its rule EC2MetaDataSSRF_BODY

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).